# Removing margins from combined ggmap plots using grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, gridextra

I am attempting to plot a 3x2 grid of six maps created with ggmap. I first set the desired margins when creating the map using `plot.margin`. Grey background added here to visualize margins. However, when combining multiple maps (duplicates of the same map for this example), new internal margins are created, spacing the maps out more than I would like.

```
require(ggmap)

map <- get_map(location = c(lon = -116.187, lat = 33.979), color = "color", 
               source = "google", maptype = "satellite", zoom = 6)

testmap <- ggmap(map) + 
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
    theme(plot.margin = margin(7.5, 7, 7, 5)) + 
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "light grey"))

grid.arrange(testmap, testmap, testmap, testmap, testmap, testmap, 
             bottom = "Longitude", left = "Latitude")
```

[image: Map grid]

Testing grid.arrange by combining six scatterplots in the same way confirms that the pre-set margins should be preserved, which is what I want for my multiple maps.

```
plot1 <- ggplot(rwr_gps, aes(x = point, y = juldate)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "light grey"))

plot1
grid.arrange(plot1, plot1, plot1, plot1, plot1, plot1, 
             bottom = "Longitude", left = "Latitude")
```

[image: Scatterplot grid]

Is there a function to further manipulate the margins when combining plots with `grid.arrange`? Alternatively, is there a way to convert ggmap plots to another object that `grid.arrange` will treat like a normal plot? Or another multiple-plotting package that can do this?

Comment: a. Can you facet instead? b. [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) is an alternative, if you like.

Comment: This happens because the maps have a fixed aspect ratio, so they can't stretch to fill the empty horizontal space: unlike the scatterplots that can, as you don't have a pre-specified aspect ratio. How would you expect the margins to be reduced?

Comment: Good point Mikko- but there must be a way to create a grid that preserves the original aspect ratio and margins. Why doesn't grid.arrange use the original plot margins to determine the final margins of the grid? What is determining the total width and margins of the grid if not the attributes of the component plots?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to convert ggmap plots to another object that grid.arrange will treat like a normal plot?

```
testmap = testmap + coord_cartesian()
```

[image]